# When adding an item programmatically the workflow 2013 will raise access denied

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, designer-workflow, remote-event-receiver

I have defined a workflow which gets fired when adding items on listA. and if i directly add an item inside listA using the UI the workflow will work well. but on listB i have a remote event receiver which programmatically create a list item inside listA.

but when the remote event receiver create an item inside listA, the workflow will raise this error:-

```
Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled in less than one minute. Details of last request: HTTP Forbidden to https://****/_api/web/lists(guid'd20db253-4447-4133-99b0-757eee9eb37e')/Items(212)?%24select=ID%2CProjectCurrentUpdate Correlation Id: 4590651d-d586-53c6-9ebc-5db114ddcfbe Instance Id: 1cf54ed9-97ee-4de3-b361-edbef338b249 

Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi SharePoint TestDev,

Please try to grant workflow app with elevated permissions. You can follow below article to achieve it.

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822159.aspx

BR